# Determining the efficiency of $2 \overline X$.

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation, statistical-inference

Let $X$ be a random variable with pdf

$$    f\left(x;\theta\right) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{3\theta^3}{(x+\theta)^4} & \text{if } 0<x<\infty \text{ and } 0 < \theta  <\infty\\
       0 &  \text{otherwise}
     \end{array}
   \right.\\$$

Show that $\hat\theta = 2\overline X$ is an unbiased estimator of $\theta$ and determine the efficiency of $\hat\theta$.

**Where I Am:**

I already showed that $\hat\theta$ is an unbiased estimator, but I'm having trouble with the second part. I know that the efficiency is given by:

$$ \text{eff}(\hat\theta) = \left(\frac{1}{nI(\theta)} \right)\left(\frac{1}{Var(\hat\theta)} \right)$$

where $I(\theta)$ is the Fisher information for $\theta$.

I was able to compute the Fisher information for $\theta$, but am having trouble with the variance of $\hat\theta$. I have the following:

$$ Var(2\overline X) = 4 Var(\overline X) = 4Var\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right) = \frac{4}{n^2}Var\left(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)$$

Now, here, I don't think I can pull the sum out because we don't know if these random variables are uncorrelated or not. Obviously, I can break it up into

$$ \sum_{i = 1}^nVar(X_i) = E\left[\left(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)^2\right] - \left(E\left[\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right]\right)^2 $$

and I can easily compute the following term:

$$ \left(E\left[\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right]\right)^2 = \frac{(n\theta)^2}{4}$$

but, I'm not sure how to deal with this guy:
$$ E\left[\left(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)^2\right] .$$

Any tips?

Comment: It's going to depend on the covariances, and you haven't told us what the covariances are (and you have given enough information that we cannot assume that they are just zero).

Comment: I think it is safe to assume that the observations are independent as they are drawn from the same distribution, and it is implied that we are taking a sample mean as the basis for the estimator.

Comment: @heropup To find the Fisher info., I just used the formula involving the integral of the partial derivative of the log of the pdf multiplied by the pdf. I actually wasn't aware that that depended upon independent observations. However, out of curiosity, I computed the variance under the assumption that the observations are i.i.d. and got a value that "makes sense," i.e. is between 0 and 1. I guess I'll just assume that that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

$$
E\left[\left(\sum_{i = 1}^nX_i\right)^2\right]=nE\left[X_1^2\right]+n(n-1)E\left[X_1]E[X_2\right]\;.
$$

The second term you already know, and you can calculate the expectation in the first term by integrating by parts (much like you probably did for $E[X_1]$):

$$
\int_0^\infty x^2\frac{3\theta^3}{(x+\theta)^4}\mathrm dx=\int_0^\infty2x\frac{\theta^3}{(x+\theta)^3}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\theta^3}{(x+\theta)^2}\mathrm dx=\theta^2\;.
$$